# POSTGIS Join tables on ST_ClosestPoint

Tags: postgis

In an attempt to join two rasters with a very small offset, the join on [`ST_ClosestPoint`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClosestPoint.html) geometry column is logical to me:

```
SELECT s.geom, s.val, c.val
FROM s
JOIN c ON ST_ClosestPoint(s.geom , c.geom) = s.geom
```

But this does not return any results.

(PostGIS v2.2.1 and PostgreSQL v9.5)

Comment: Perhaps try with [ST_SnapToGrid](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_SnapToGrid.html), the raster version, and use ST_Intersects for the join condition?

Comment: what is an example of the actual geometry of s.geom and c.geom?  eg: 'POINT(-90.3928339896896 36.7569372904341)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ST_ClosestPoint` returns an actual point, not a boolean as would be needed for a JOIN.

See also [PostGIS: ST_ClosestPoint join error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352900/postgis-st-closestpoint-join-error)