# PostGIS: ST_ClosestPoint join error

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, knn

I have two tables: one with geom points of species and an other one with height contour lines geoms. My Idea was to find per specie geom the closest point to a contour 'geom' line and then select its elevation. So I can find out between which elevations I can find a specific species

My though was the following:

```
SELECT od.elevation
FROM shp_opendem od
     JOIN species sp ON ST_ClosestPoint(sp.geom, od.geom)
WHERE sp.name = 'somename'
```

This isn't running as ST_ClosestPoint is not a boolean which is required in a join.
The exact error message:

```
ERROR:  argument of JOIN/ON must be type boolean, not type geometry
```

Any tips how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a *(K) Nearest Neighbor* search with one result per input:

```
SELECT sp.*,
       cnt.elevation
FROM   species AS sp
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT elevation
  FROM   shp_opendem AS od
  ORDER BY
         sp.geom <-> od.geom
  LIMIT  1
) AS cnt
-- WHERE sp.name = 'somename'
;
```

This will find the closes contour to each point and returns its `od.elevation` along with all columns of the `species` table.

The special [`<->`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) distance operator is highly optimized for index driven distance searches when used in the `ORDER BY` expression; make sure you have a **spatial index in place** on your tables, and ran table maintenance prior to this query!

---

For more info on the overall concept:

- [Efficient way to find nearest feature between huge postgres tables](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297208/efficient-way-to-find-nearest-feature-between-huge-postgres-tables/297244#297244)
- [Get barrier edge id](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283794/get-barrier-edge-id/283797#283797)
- [Find closest polygon from point and get its attributes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338312/find-closest-polygon-from-point-and-get-its-attributes/338328#338328)
- [How to UPDATE with LATERAL Nearest-Neighbour query?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278357/how-to-update-with-lateral-nearest-neighbour-query/278362#278362)