# Find all closest points to unique point in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, point, sql, st-distance, knn

I have two tables `valid_collisions` (POINT) and `intrct_pts` (POINT)

I want to create a new table using a nearest-neighbor type of query to find aggregate values from my `valid_collisions`. In essence I am looking for the geometry of the `intrsct_pts` and the aggregated values from `valid_collisions` based off the *distance* of the compared geometries.

Example of some code I have

```sql
SELECT PT.GEOM, PT.CT, PT.ID,
       SUM(VC.PERSONS) AS PEOPLE_INJ,
       SUM(VC.MOTORIST) AS MOTOR_INJ,
       COUNT(*) AS INCIDENT_CT
FROM   PUBLIC.VALID_COLLISIONS AS VC, 
       PUBLIC.INTRSCT_PTS AS PT
WHERE PT.GEOM(LIMIT 1)***
ORDER BY ST_DISTANCE(VC.GEOM, PT.GEOM) DESC;
```

The `LIMIT` is an error (just there for temp code), but I know that I need to limit the aggregated values and selections by each unique `pt.geom`. But how would I go about this through using a spatial call like `ST_Distance` to find all closest `vc.geom` values to `pt.geom` records?

Comment: The list of tables in the TABLES clause really needs to be stamped out, replaced by modern use of the JOIN clause. This has the side effect of letting you focus on the join rule in isolation, so you can't leave it out of the WHERE accidentally. You're also missing a GROUP BY for aggregation.  You've tagged this with KNN -- have you researched the KNN operator and/or ST_DWithin?

Comment: Hi Vince, I've researched those methods but in this case I don't need and index of distance value(i.e. 30m). All points I have fall within a distance to begin with. I assume the GROUP BY I am missing takes care of the unique `pt.geom` values by saying `GROUP BY pt.geom`. Also, I can use the JOIN call on the collisions data: ` FROM public.intrsct_pts as pt  JOIN public.collisions as vc (ST_...) ORDER BY pt.geom`

Comment: Could you give us more details about your tables? This query uses Cartesian join which is usually not effective enough. You must use GROUP BY on the columns which are without aggregator function in the result (e.g. GROUP BY PT.GEOM, PT.CT, PT.ID).  It is not clear why do you want LIMIT 1? Do you want to use only the nearest point? But that case no sense to use aggregate function. Please give sample data and sample result what you would like to get.

Comment: @StevenNac even if all collisions are within e.g. 30m of an intersection to begin with, if your data is missing a relational attribute that links those collisions to intersections, you need to explicitly *create* that link; you will have to `JOIN` the tables `ON ST_DWithin` with the given threshold and e.g. `GROUP BY pt.<primary_key>`.

Comment: Are you looking for `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` ? As asked by Zoltan, it would be useful to give us the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using ST_DWithin and was able to retrieve a result:

```
SELECT 
pt.geom, pt.id,
 SUM(VC.PERSONS) AS PEOPLE_INJ,
 SUM(VC.MOTORIST) AS MOTOR_INJ,
 COUNT(*) AS INCIDENT_CT
FROM  public.intrsct_pts as pt
JOIN public.valid_collisions as vc
ON ST_DWITHIN(vc.geom, pt.geom, 30.0) 
GROUP BY pt.id
ORDER BY incident_ct DESC;
```

-NOTE: this will return *ALL* collision points that fall within 30m of each point (i.e. some points will be included in multiple different intersections). I'm pretty sure there is a more efficient way to only include each collision using a `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` and `<->` for each `vc.geom` and `pt.geom`. Will post a reply if I find the solution

Comment: see e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/352905 with links to further info on the concept

Comment: I was able to figure it out doing something similarly, used this article by Paul Ramsey as a guide: https://carto.com/blog/lateral-joins/

Comment: `SELECT 
pt.geom, pt.id,
 SUM(VC.PERSONS) AS PEOPLE_INJ,
 SUM(VC.MOTORIST) AS MOTOR_INJ,
 COUNT(*) AS INCIDENT_CT
FROM  intersections.geom        FROM
 (SELECT * FROM
 public.valid_collisions
 ) as vc
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
   (SELECT pt.id, pt.geom
    FROM public.intrsct_pts as pt
    ORDER BY
      vc.geom <-> pt.geom
    LIMIT 1
   ) as intersections
GROUP BY pid, intersections.geom
ORDER BY incident_ct DESC);       `